# Google Appscript VALUE not returned

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms, array-formulas

I'm a complete newbie to programming but wants to learn how. What I did is, I created a google form with 8 questions and the responses goes to a spreadsheet. Now what I want to do is to add another column on the spreadsheet, like a unique ID(should be a sequence like 10001, 10002, 10003, etc.) so I have a unique modifier, in that way once the form is submitted, that unique ID, will also increment by 1.

So far what I did is I created an array on the spreadsheet Unique ID column with this formula:
`=arrayformula(if(row(A2:A)=1,"Unique ID",if(len(A2:A)>0,9999+row(A2:A),iferror(1/0))))`

But, I don't know how to call the value on the google script editor. (example cell: I2 the value is 10001, I3 = 10002). Can you anyone help me with this please? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say `But, I don't know how to call the value` ?

Comment: My advice is to leave the linked sheets alone and do whatever it is that you wish to do on another sheet and let the form have it's own sheets.  It works well and it will keeping on working and you won't loose any data.  Perhaps you can build your new sheet with [onFormSubmit.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: @Cooper: Hi, I'm sorry if I'm not explaining it right. What I mean is, since I used the arrayformula, the unique ID gets automatically generated once there is an entry submitted on the forms. So, what I want to get is the value of that newly generated unique ID so it will display on the confirmation page after submitting the form to serve as a reference ID. I hope this helps clarify it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use `onFormSubmit()` trigger then I believe `e.range.rowStart` should be the row that was just submitted.  All you need to know is the column.

Comment: You won't be able to display the ID on the form submitted confirmation page unfortunately. The easiest way would be to email the ID to the person after they have submitted or build the form in a web app.

Comment: @Cooper: I’ll look that function and will go from there. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't use Google Forms very much so James D. is probably correct about not being able to get the ID sent back in the form confirmation page.  My understand is that once the Google Form launches there is little or no interactivity with it programattically.

Comment: @JamesD: I see, I thought it would be possible. But you're right, sending an email is much easier so there is an actual trail instead of copy and pasting it from the "Thank you" page after the form is submitted.

If it's not much of a bother, may I know what the syntax would be? I don't know how to pull up the Unique ID value on that particular submission, but I do know how to trigger the sending of an email. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Cooper: I see, I didn't know that. Yeah I am actually considering the sending of an email instead. I'm still stuck on how to get the value though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Getting your Id from the Form's Linked Sheet**

```
   function onFormSubmit(e) {
      if(e.values && !e.values[1])return;//make question one a required question.  This will keep you from sending emails due to spurious triggers.
      var colnum='enter the column number of you id';//A=1,B=2...
      var id=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,colnum).getDisplayValue();

    }
```

Please note: You can not run a function like this from the Script Editor so to avoid the inevitable question I'll simply point out that this requires a trigger to test it.  Or you have to figure out a way to provide it with an event object.

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I can't upvote though, just click on the checkmark instead.